# $_SESSION[] Not Getting Set

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm making a login system, and when I send a request from an AJAX connection, the session is not getting set.
Sending the connection:

```
function onSubmit(form){
    var username = form.username.value;
    var password = form.password.value;
    if(username == ''){
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='<font color="red"><b>Please enter a username</b></font>';
        return;
    }
    if(password == ''){
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='<font color="red"><b>Please enter a password</b></font>';
        return;
    }
    if(username != '' && password != ''){
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='';
        showDiv('loadinglogin');    
        var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "util/login.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function(msg) {  
        if(msg == "ok"){
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='<font color="green"><b>Login good, redirecting</b></font>';
            hideDiv('loadinglogin');    
            window.location = "test.php";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='<font color="red"><b>Invalid login</b></font>';
            hideDiv('loadinglogin');    
        }
      }  
    }); 



    }
}
```

Setting the session/handle login:

```
<?php
include('database.php');
session_start();
function in_db($u,$p){
    $p = md5($p);
    $p = sha1($p);
    $p = sha1($p);
    $p = md5($p);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$u' AND `password` = '$p'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    { 
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
} 
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !isset($$_SESSION['user']) && !isset($$_SESSION['pass'])){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    if(in_db($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
        print("ok");
    }else{
        print("bad");
    }
}else{
    print("bad");
}
?>
```

Not sure if I'm doing somthing wrong :/

EDIT: I pulled this from ERROR_LOG

[18-Oct-2012 07:27:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in /util/login.php on line 2

PHP.ini

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 60
variables_order = "EGPCS"
extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
precision = 12
SMTP = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="


; Only uncomment zend optimizer lines if your application requires Zend Optimizer support

;[Zend]
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3
;zend_extension=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-3.3.3/ZendExtensionManager.so
;zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.3.3/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so


; -- Be very careful to not to disable a function which might be needed!
; -- Uncomment the following lines to increase the security of your PHP site.

;disable_functions = "highlight_file,ini_alter,ini_restore,openlog,passthru,
;             phpinfo, exec, system, dl, fsockopen, set_time_limit,
;                     popen, proc_open, proc_nice,shell_exec,show_source,symlink"
```

Comment: There's a whole lot of wrong going on here. Almost on every line. I advice you start something with basic tutorial.

Comment: @itachi I've worked in PHP before. I really don't see anything wrong, besides the double $, which I fixed.

Comment: If this is the error message you got, the you need to check your php.ini file for section [Session] and see if you using the recommended values.

Comment: Indeed. how does your php.ini look?

Comment: Not necessarily the root of your problem but you are using md5, sha1.... That too twice! What's the point of it? 2nd, you are using myql_* function which is deprecated. 3rd, mysql_real_escape_string is vulnerable, 4th put session at the top, 5th use pdo with prepared statement, 6th use proper hashing.... Etc. Its not related to your problem but something you need to put attention.

Comment: Look at [Session] section in your php.ini, you should have some lines of code there, if not - maybe this is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `session_start();` at very beginning of your file, before `include()`.

Comment: Beginning of file doesn't matter. Only important point is that no other output is being done before session is set as it is part of the HTTP headers.

Comment: Indeed but what if there's whitespaces involved? Better to put at the very beginning than to get errors later?

Comment: I agree with @itachi, it`s better to put it at very beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code- what is $$_SESSION['user']? Should be $_SESSION?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#82957)

and check your $$_SESSION typo.

Addionally, please try

```
print(session_id());
```

before starting your session.

Also try

```
session_id("my_session");
```

before starting your session and let us know the results.